# How to push user to the current route but with new parameters using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am an experienced vue.js dev learning React.

The application I am working on has an `account` dropdown, that allows the user to change the active account they are viewing within the app. A user should be able to change the account from any page. This means the route would be changed on account selection.

In Vue I am able to do this with:

```
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const route = useRoute()

    function pushTo(accountId) {
      router.push({
        name: route.name,
        params: {
          accountId,
        },
      })
    }
  },
}
```

I am not sure how to cleanly do this using `react-router-dom`.

The `useLocation` hook is returning the string url as `/account/123/assets`.

The `useParams` hook returns `{ accountId: 123 }`.

Is there a simple way to say `push user to the currentRoute with a new param`, or do I need to manually parse the string url `/account/123/assets` and replacing the `123` with the new value?

Comment: Why can't you push to the same path with the new route path params, e.g. `"/account/456/assets"`? What is the React code you are trying to use? See [mcve].

Comment: I am looking for a clean way to tell the router to "push the user to the currentRoute with new parameters".

Opps submitted, editing with more details.

Comment: What is more clean than `navigate("/account/456/assets")`? Or if you need to inject the value ```navigate(`/account/${accountId}/assets`)```? Or `navigate(generatePath("/account/:account/assets", { accountId })`?

Comment: I need a way to identify the current route, and insert the correct parameters. I could do `navigate("/account/456/assets")` for assets, but if they are on another route, I also need to be able to change the accountId, ie: "/account/456/admin".

I was attempting to use `useLocation` for this information, but since it returns the path as `/account/123/assets` I don't have a clear indicator of what the current route is without parsing the string manually, and replacing the `123` with `456`. I was hoping that there was a simpler way of knowing the current route, and inserting the new parameter.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the component doing the navigating either (a) doesn't know the route it's rendered on, or (b) doesn't know where it wants to link to. Seeing a complete [mcve] for what you are trying to work with, including package versions, may help clear this up.

Comment: The component doing the navigation is in the header on all pages. It looks like `generatePath` could work, but I need the route as `/account/:accountId/...` but `useLocation` is returning it as `/account/123/...`. Is there a method the router provides for this?

Comment: It kind of depends on what version of RRD you are using.

Comment: This is really frustrating.  I've been trying to do the same thing.  In my case, users can switch "facilities" on every "facility" page.  I'd like to say, "redirect to the current page but with a new facilityId."  This should be pretty trivial but it's surprisingly complicated with RRD.